# MSBuild Error Failed to read in data for

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-3.5

I have read numerous MSBuild posts, but none seem to refer to a strange problem I am having.

In MSBuild.xml (.NET 3.5) I have the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <JavaScriptFiles Include="..\js\jquery.translator-ms-1.0.0-debug-all.js" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I receive an error:
Error   188 Failed to read in the data for the path/file [..\js\jquery.translator-ms-1.0.0-debug-all.js]. The most **common** cause for this is because the path is incorrect or the file name is incorrect ... so please check your path and file names.

However, if I use a file in the very same folder as follows with like properties:

The build completes successfully.

Does anyone know the **"uncommon"** causes for this error?

Comment: Might the file be open in some other process?

Comment: Thanks, but it turned out to be a pesky "Debugger" statement in the js file.

Comment: I should have mentioned the purpose of this build is to compress the JavaScript file using the Yahoo Yui Compressor, and that the code is error free.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons for being unable to open and/or read a file:

- It doesn't exist.
- It is open in another process (either for exclusive access, or it's locked).
- You don't have NTFS permissions.
- You want write access but the file has the read-only attribute.
- The combined length of the path and (your quite long) filename exceeds MAX_PATH (260) characters.
- The file is on a remote server and there's a network problem.
- You've run out of kernel resources (e.g. too many files or handles in general open).  This is quite unlikely.
- You have a physical disk error.

Comment: Thanks, I will know what to look for when future problems like this arise. In this case, there was a "Debugger" statement in the js file that caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that having the "debugger" statement within this JavaScript file was the "uncommon" error in this case.